# F#: how to access elements in an enumerated way from JSON file?

Tags: json, f#, f#-data

I love F# type providers and that's why I try to use FSharp.Data library whenever I can, but I've found a use case that doesn't seem covered.

Consider this simple JSON file:

```
{
    "Foo": {
        "Baz": 0,
        "Bazz": "x"
    },
    "Bar": {
        "Baz": 10,
        "Bazz": "y"
    }
}
```

I want to parse the elements above as an array rather than accessing Foo's and Bar's elements in a hardcoded way. That is, receiving an `IEnumerable<SomeRecord>`, where SomeRecord has 2 members `Baz` and `Bazz`. Is it possible to use JsonProvider API in some way to achieve this?

I tried the `SampleIsList=true` option but doesn't seem to work:

```
type MyJsonProvider = JsonProvider<"./elements.json",
                                   EmbeddedResource="MyAssemblyName, elements.json",
                                   SampleIsList=true>

let SomeReadingMethod() =
    let assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
    let embeddedServerListFileName = "elements.json"
    use stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(embeddedServerListFileName)
    use reader = new StreamReader(stream)
    let list = reader.ReadToEnd()

    let elements = MyJsonProvider.Parse(list)
    for element in elements do
        ...
```

I get the compiler error: `The type JsonProvider<...>.Root is not a type whose values can be enumerated with this syntax...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to use JsonProvider API in some way to achieve this?

No, the sample input you're providing is a *map* from keys/fields to values—not an enumeration of values. `SampleIsList` is meant for when your sample itself is a collection that contains multiple instances of the type you're inferring. If you want to use `JsonProvider` with this I think you're going to need to alter your JSON schema both at design- and run-time.

Alternatively, I'd consider writing a simple parser, either using the [JSON parsing features in FSharp.Data](http://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/library/JsonValue.html) or one of the other OSS F# JSON parsing libraries. Here's a rudimentary example:

```
open FSharp.Data
open FSharp.Data.JsonExtensions

let info =
  JsonValue.Parse(""" 
    {
    "Foo": {
        "Baz": 0,
        "Bazz": "x"
    },
    "Bar": {
        "Baz": 10,
        "Bazz": "y"
    }
} """)
type MyRecord = {
  Baz : int;
  Bazz : string
}
let parse props =
  seq {
    for (_k,v) in props ->
      {Baz = v?Baz.AsInteger(); Bazz = v?Bazz.AsString()}
  }

> parse info.Properties;;
val it : seq<MyRecord> =
  seq [{Baz = 0; Bazz = "x";};
       {Baz = 10; Bazz = "y";}]
```

Comment: in your example you're not able to access the strings of the keys, such as Foo and Bar, any way to do it?

Comment: @knocte that's what `_k` represents in my example: the keys.